# PHP var (051) gets the value 41 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, variables

So I'm using the variable `$intSNr = $_REQUEST["SNr"];`
And it works all right, it gets **051** everywhere in the variables, I tried to echo them all.
Now when I press on a button on this site -

```
`<input type="button" value="Save changes" name="Save" onClick="doSubmit(this.form,<?php echo $intSNr.','.$anotherNr ?>)">`
```

which leads to the javascript function

```
function doSubmit(f,snr,ID)  
{  
  f.method="post";
  f.action="testings7.php?SNr="+snr+"&orderID="+ID;  
  f.vFreigabe.value=1;  
  alert(snr);  
  //f.submit();  
}
```

And because some users had problems which kicked them back to the login site when
they clicked the button, I tried to alert the value - And the value became **41** instead of **051**?!

I tried afterswards with a hidden input value of `$intSNr` and

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');  
var testsnr = test.value;
```

and alerted `testsnr` - and voilá it became 051?
So what the heck is happening that my `$intSNr` gets the right value with
a hidden value field but **not** when I pass snr in **doSubmit**?

Comment: `oct51 == dec41`

Comment: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero, scroll to "0 as a prefix".

Comment: php treat number start with `0` as octal

Comment: If you use `'use strict'` you should get a warning.

Comment: Octal or no octal, if you want to keep the leading zero you must use String data type instead of Number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript all numbers started from `0` are `octal`.

Comment: See the comment about using 'use strict'.

Comment: If you prefix an non-octal number you'd expect `NaN` but you get a decimal, eg `08 == 8`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
onClick="doSubmit(this.form,<?php echo (int) $intSNr.','.$anotherNr ?>)">
```

With javascript, a number with a leading zero is an octal number, so `051` is equal to `41`. Parsing it to an int should solve the problem.

Comment: or echo intval( $intSNr )

Answer (score 0):

Write you button code as mentioned below

```
<input type="button" value="Save changes" name="Save" onClick="doSubmit(this.form,'<?php echo $intSNr; ?>', '<?php echo $anotherNr; ?>' )">
```